# How does Partitioning Tables affect stored procedures and functions?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Hi I have table that has huge records. This is killing the  performance of stored procedure's and function's. I decided to partion the table. Will this affect any kind of coding in the stored procs  or functions?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using - SQLServer or MySQL (or something else)?

Comment: How have you concluded that partitioning will improve performance?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 . Its not a conclusion. we are actually thinking of it.

Comment: [You might find this answer useful then](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5109333/73226)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write about your database engine, but generally table pertioning doesn't affect on stored proc and function code.

Will it improve yout perfomance - it depends on your query and table structure.