# MySQL Partitioning: Performance increase For multiple partitioned tables. Why?

Tags: mysql, performance, parallel-processing, data-partitioning

I have implemented a benchmark which tests the permanence of reads and writes on 10 different tables.

I have 10 java threads , each performs queries on its table only:

Threads 1 performs operations on Table1,
Threads 2 performs operations on Table2,

I have compered the performance of running those threads in parallel executing multiple reads on non partitioned Table[1-10], vs the performance of the same benchmark while partitioning each TableX to 9 equal partitions (each represents a week of measurements, total 9 weeks of data).

I have received interesting and non explainable results:

The performance of a single operation for a single thread is two times better for a non partitioned table, while the total time of all operations for all threads is 5 times faster for the partitioned tables.

I checked the logs, and noticed that partitioned tables enable more operations to be paralleled, and although a single operation is longer, multiple operations for different threads are paralleled , and therefore finish faster.

I don't understand why is this happen, since each thread execute operations only on its own table???

I am using only MyISAM engine for all my tables and partitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the given article that how Partitioning help to improve server performance

[How To Decide if You Should Use Table Partitioning](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-decide-if-should-use-table-partitioning/)

and also almost same question answered by expert check it out

[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109134/sql-server-2008-partitioned-table-and-parallelism)